# Gerrit- Invalid Server Id when

Tags: gerrit

I came into a problem with invalid server id in Gerrit.

Here is the error info:

*skipping change 1152942 in project platform/external/ltp because of an invalid server id [CONTEXT project="platform/external/ltp" ]*

*com.google.gerrit.server.notedb.InvalidServerIdException: invalid server id, expected 639b8ee7-1666-4b5d-8636-2fedfaf8ef27: actual: 7f82688b-25e6-4dc5-a12f-69ad0cdd1fa5*

How can I fix it ?
Many thanks and appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Server Id is the server identifier, normally it's automatically set randomly and stored in the "gerrit" section of the GERRIT-SITE/etc/gerrit.config configuration file.

Ex:

```
[gerrit]
    serverId = c5c147e8-9723-4ba5-bf44-92e653789f9c
```

See more details at the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#gerrit.serverId).

Have you (maybe accidentally) changed its value?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I deleted the serverid and restarted gerrit.It works.

Comment: BTW how this server id generated and what's the format.Not mentioned in Gerrit Doc.

Comment: By the Gerrit doc, it set a random UUID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: I  delete the serverId and restart but failed. The error msg is still 'com.google.gerrit.server.notedb.InvalidServerIdException: invalid server id'.BTW my Gerrit-site  floder is copied from one Gerrit Server

Comment: Two months ago, you said it worked!

Comment: Sorry...Marcelo.But its different this time. I copied the whole Gerrit-site folder and restart it on another machine. Only keep the serverId as the old one can it work well. I  guess somewhere has a relationship between the changes and serverId ?

Comment: I think it would be better if you create a new question for that.